# Интеграция компьютерных программ с POS системой

Tags: python, c#

Интеграция компьютерных программ с POS системой. Соединения бесконтактного аппарата безналичной оплаты(это может быть и онлайн пос системой) с компьютерной программой для выполнения определенных функции. На примере, клиент хочет получить услугу в компьютере, и для этого ему необходимо сначала произвести оплату через QR или же через банковскую карту. И после этого клиент сможет получит нужную ему услугу. Вопрос заключается в том что, как все этого можно сделать? как правильно все этого сделать? алгоритм действий? Я сам не разработчик. Если есть разработчики прошу помочь, я оплачу.

Comment: Вопрос то в чём?

Comment: что для этого нужно? Как это можно сделать ? Я сам не разработчик и не знаю как система работает

Comment: Вы можете редактировать свой вопрос. Вот и напишите там, что вы хотите, собственно.

Comment: написал что мне нужно, Спасибо!

Comment: Насчёт сделать за деньги это вам на сайты фриланса всё-таки, здесь немного другое

Answer (score 0):

Первое - нужно описать какую услугу будете оказывать. Что делает пользователь, что получает при оплате. Это нужно чтоб понять как соединить вашу программу и программы оборудования.

С POS терминалом самое простое это сбербанк.

Вы запускаете программу `sb_pilot 1 100` терминал просит оплату 1 рубль, при успешной оплате появляется файл `e` в котором написано "УСПЕШНО".

Самое важное найти точку в которой можно прервать программу и получить оплату

Comment: Вы не могли бы это сделать? Я оплачу услугу ? поподробнее я могу писать в почту